# How to get keyEvent to work in Java?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, keyevent, key-events

I'm completely new at programming Java. I can't get my `keyEvent`s to wont work. I need this for a little game I'm making. Here is my code:

```
package markusrytter.pingpong;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    static int ballX;
    static int ballY;
    static int ballR = 15;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(ballX - ballR, ballY - ballR, ballR * 2, ballR * 2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Frame");
        main game = new main();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(1400, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        ballX = frame.getContentPane().getSize().width / 2;
        ballY = frame.getContentPane().getSize().height / 2;

        while (true) {
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("A key is Pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            System.out.println("Spacebutton pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

I do hope someone can help, I have tried to watch videos but again, I'm new at java.

Comment: (1-) not sure why this got so many up votes. The OP states they read articles and copied the code directly. Don't you think the code should work if it was copied directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most importantly: change the name of your class. It's called main and that's a bad idea. Also it's much more advisable to override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint`.

You didn't add the keylistener to the `JFrame`. You should call this in your main *after* creating `game`:

```
frame.addKeyListener(game);
```

You also need to add the remaining `KeyListener` methods.

and that should do it.

Comment: Then it says: cannot use this in a static reference

Comment: @markusrytter notice my edit. (changed `this` to `game`)

Comment: @markusrytter No problem. however, you should change the `paint` method to `paintComponent`

Comment: @ItamarGreen, nice of you to keep copying my suggestions.

Comment: @camickr Or, instead of that, I actually answered it without noticing that answered it too, and simply know the things you suggested. I find it better to first show someone what they did right before showing what they did wrong, rather then the other way around.

Comment: @markusrytter, the KeyListener should be added in the class that extends the JPanel. That is the code for the class should be self contained. The handling of the keyboard is a function of the class, not the main() method. Keep related code logically together in the same class so there are no dependencies. You really need to take a look at all the advice I gave you.

Comment: @markusrytter he is quite right, of course. I gave an answer that works, but I neglected to show were you could improve it.

Comment: @ItamarGreen `I gave an answer that works` - yes it works but is not really correct for the reason I gave above. Just getting something to work is not the way to answer a question, especially when there is a simple way to improve the suggestion by changing the placement of a single line of code. And for that reason I decided to down vote the answer (1-). Again the functionality is implement in the JPanel class so the listener should be added in the JPanel class, not externally.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your code won't compile since you didn't implement KeyListener (completely)
2. You didn't add the key listener to the panel in its constructor.
3. KeyEvents are only dispatched to components with focus. Your panel is not focusable so it will never receive events. You use the method `setFocusable(true)`.
4. Don't override paint(). Instead you should be overriding `paintComponent(...)`.
5. You shouldn't even be using a KeyListener. Instead when using Swing you should be using `Key Bindings`.
6. Don't use static variables for the properties of your class.
7. Your GUI is not created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.

> i have read articles, i have watched videos, and done everything exactly like them,

Obviously not or it would work.

For a proper tutorial start with the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on:

1. How to Write a KeyListener
2. Custom Painting
3. Key Bindings.
4. Concurrency